# If a user has access to multiple encrypted pieces of data with AES encryption, would they be able to guess the encryption key?

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, rncryptor

I've started using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), which describes itself as "CCCryptor (AES encryption) wrappers for iOS and Mac".

My question isn't specific to iOS, but is more general.

Here's some code I might use to encrypt a string:

```
func encryptText(text: String, encryptionKey: String) -> NSData? {
    let textData = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if textData == nil { 
        return nil 
    } 

    let encryptedTextData = RNCryptor.encryptData(textData!, password: encryptionKey)

    return encryptedTextData
}
```

I have a few concerns:

1. If a user doesn't have access to the encryption key, but there were multiple strings encrypted with the same encryption key that they did have access to, would they be able to figure out what the encryption key is?
2. If a user knows the contents of one of the strings, for example "Test String", would they be able to figure out the encryption key using that knowledge, and thus access the other strings?
3. If yes to 2, would adding a series of random characters to the end of each string (lets say 20 characters) secure me from that type of attack? If someone had that knowledge, would it be easy for them to remove the last 20 characters and decrypt the remaining string?

Comment: Brute force attack is usually very expensive computationally speaking, so for "normal uses" it should hold well. for a more robust system, try to use async cryptography. I also recommend you to ask in http://security.stackexchange.com , they may have more to talk about it.

Comment: A brute force attack against AES is not only computationally expensive but infeasible, it just isn't a concern if a random key is used.

Comment: Using asynchronous keys (public-private key), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: Not asynchronous, *asymmetric*.  And it's not more "robust" than secret-key-crypto. It "just" makes key management easier.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption is generally not used to encrypt data because the size of the data is limited to the key size and it is very slow. The advantage is there are separate keys to encrypt and decrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All an attacker could do is brute-force the key, which is not a realistic proposition, and one that does not get easier with the knowledge of multiple messages (unless there is some weakness in AES that we are not aware of that would produce "patterns").

You may be wondering if there are other advantages to an attacker if he gains access to many intercepted (or even decrypted) messages. For example the ability to guess a plaintext if it was similar or even identical to an earlier message.

AES includes setting an "initialization vector".

Usually, you set a random IV for every message and send that along with the encrypted message. Your library is doing that as well. The result is that no two messages are encrypted in exactly the same way. Even if you send the same plaintext three times, it will end up in three disparate ciphertexts (indistinguishable from three different messages). Same idea as "salting".

> would adding a series of random characters to the end of each string (lets say 20 characters) secure me from that type of attack?

The random IV mechanism makes this unnecessary.

As for it being effective, AES is a block cipher. The output of earlier blocks can affect the output of later blocks, but not the other way around. So a random padding at the end will only change the last block. If anything, you'd want to pad your string at the beginning. But again, the algorithm itself (if used properly) has mechanisms to deal with these concerns (in the form of IV, block chaining and block padding).

Comment: Could you tell us what would happen without the initialisation vector or with a fixed initialisation vector? Obviously I could figure out that you sent two identical messages, or for example that you sent two messages where the first n bytes were the same; can I get more than that?

Comment: I believe that is about the extent of it. You could tell if two messages start out the same (or are completely identical) without needing to decrypt them. Should not make any difference in your brute-forcing attempts (so maybe my answer was a bit confused about that). The IV is supposedly also known to the attacker (as it is commonly included in the transmission itself).